# upload a file without a temporary file using request module nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-upload, stream, request, zip

Im trying to zip a bunch of files and uploaded it to remote server(which is also written by nodejs and using multiparty for form processing)

but what I want to achieve is to do that without a temporary file. that mean": **create a zip archive as stream and upload the stream directly through `request` module.**"

so I write some test code, first is the server to receive upload:

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/upload' && req.method === 'POST') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new multiparty.Form({encoding: null});
    console.log("what?");
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }

      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });

    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
}).listen(8080);
```

Then I just execute `zip` command using child_process, but instead of creating a temp file, I output the archive to stdout in order to create a stream:

```
/*
    upload a manually-created readable stream from string output from zip command.
*/
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var dir = '/Users/drakedan/Documents/screenshot/1457950544039/';

var zipCmd = 'zip -r9 - ' + dir;

var Stream = require('stream');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
exec(zipCmd, {encoding: null}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    var rs = Stream.Readable({encoding: null});

    rs.push(stdout);
    rs.push(null);

    var req = request.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload', function(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        console.log(body);
    });
    var form = req.form();
    form.append('image', rs);

})
```

But after i run the upload script, the server return

`{ [Error: stream ended unexpectedly] status: 400, statusCode: 400 }`

just seems like there is something wrong with that readable stream.

in order to check if there is any corruption inside the content of that stream. I modify the script to using a temp file.

```
/*
    first write the stream content to a temp file, then 
    upload a new stream from the temp file.
*/
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var dir = '/Users/drakedan/Documents/screenshot/1457950544039/';

var zipCmd = 'zip -r9 - ' + dir;

var Stream = require('stream');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
exec(zipCmd, {encoding: null}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    var rs = Stream.Readable({encoding: null});

    rs.push(stdout);
    rs.push(null);


    var ws = fs.createWriteStream('/Users/drakedan/Desktop/test.zip');
    rs.pipe(ws);// create a temp file.

    rs.on('end', function(){
        var req = request.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload', function(err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            console.log(body);
        });
        var form = req.form();
        form.append('image', fs.createReadStream('/Users/drakedan/Desktop/test.zip')); // readstream from temp file
    });

});
```

This time, the server accept the file.

```
received upload:

{ fields: {}, files: { image: [ [Object] ] } }
```

and the temp file can be decompressed successfully which mean no corruption of the content.

So my question is:

**what is the right way to deal with this situation?**

**what is the difference between the `fs.createReadStream` and a readable stream I created manually.**

**is there any chance I can stream through the whole process?**

**what have I done wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around quite a lot, I think I find a way to tackle the problem.

the `stream ended unexpectedly` error based on my assumption, is mainly because the server side doesn't know where the stream actually end. say the size of the file is not known. I got some hint form this [blog](http://qnimate.com/stream-file-uploads-to-storage-server-in-node-js/) which change the `transfer-encoding:'chunked'` header. after I do the same, the server seems accept the form, not as a uploaded file but as a normal field.

That is a progress!  and then I revisit the [form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data) and [request](https://github.com/request/request) I finally figure out the right way to do that.

There is 2 ways to solve the problem:

1. constructing the formData using custom form option, put stdout directly as content. give it a correct content-type then submit it, and its done.

   ```
   var exec = require('child_process').exec;
   var dir = '/Users/drakedan/Documents/screenshot/1457950544039/';

   var zipCmd = 'zip -r9 - ' + dir;

   var Stream = require('stream');
   var request = require('request');
   var fs = require('fs');
   var FormData = require('form-data');
   exec(zipCmd, {encoding: null}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
       if (err) console.error(err);

       var form = new FormData();
       form.append('image', stdout, {
           filename: 'upload.zip',
           contentType: 'application/zip, application/octet-stream'
       });

       form.submit('http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload', function(err, res) {
           if (err) throw err;
           console.log(res);
       });
   });
   ```

2.using manually created readable stream. although its seems unnecessary
in this case, but still good to know. the key point is **define the knownLength**, otherwise the `stream ended unexpectedly` would occur.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var dir = '/Users/drakedan/Documents/screenshot/1457950544039/';

var zipCmd = 'zip -r9 - ' + dir;

var Stream = require('stream');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var FormData = require('form-data');
exec(zipCmd, {encoding: null}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    var rs = Stream.Readable({encoding: null});

    rs.push(stdout);
    rs.push(null);

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('image', rs, {
        filename: 'upload.zip',
        contentType: 'application/zip, application/octet-stream',
        knownLength: 116089 // necessary if using custom steam
    });

    form.submit('http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload', function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('done');
    });
});
```

By understanding what had happened, I can just change the code using `request` to get job done. using custom file options

```
var formData = {
    image: {
        value: stdout,
        options: {
            filename: 'upload.zip',
            contentType: 'application/zip, application/octet-stream'
        }
    }
}

var req = request.post({url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload', formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log(body);
});
```